# php - don't show notice error

Tags: php

i don't get notice when i try to echo a variable that not declare.
Why ?

```
    error_reporting  =  E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
    display_errors = On
    error_log = "F:\phperror.log"

    zend_extension_ts="F:\work\xampp168w7\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
    xdebug.remote_enable=true
    xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
    xdebug.remote_port=9000
    xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
    xdebug.profiler_enable=1
    xdebug.profiler_output_dir="F:\work\xampp168w7\tmp"
```

Comment: `In PHP 4 and PHP 5 the default value is E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE. This setting does not show E_NOTICE level errors.`

Comment: i use this and it work fine on winxp but not win7. Only fine when set error_reporting  =  E_ALL

Answer (score 5):

```
;   - Show all errors, except for notices and coding standards warnings
;
;error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
```

~E_NOTICE is 'no notices' I believe. Try just `error_reporting  = E_ALL`

Unsure if echoing an undefined variable would cause an E_NOTICE though.

Edit: apparently echoing an undefined variable does report an E_NOTICE :) (see comments)

Comment: Any time you attempt to use a `$variable` that has not been defined, an E_NOTICE is generated.

Answer (score 3):

Change your ini setting to:

```
 error_reporting  =  E_ALL
```

or, during runtime:

```
 ini_set( 'error_reporting', E_ALL );
```

Comment: i normanly use error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE , but when use on Win7 i don't get notice. don't know why :-s

Comment: Your winxp machine might be using a different php.ini config